# Docker swarm scaling down task with session: Stop maintaining number of task per service

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, autoscaling, docker-swarm-mode

I have running `n` tasks in service `A`. The containers are created by `docker service scale A=n`.
The service maintains a session with a user so I cannot use `docker swarm scale A=n-1`

**How do I force docker to stop maintaining the number `n` of containers for service `A`?**

I would like to run something like `docker service scale A=ignore` and let the containers stop by themselves. The containers would scale down when their internal state allows them to.